# HTML5 local storage to save notes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I created this [note web app](https://jsfiddle.net/imacange/0p937xsn/) that allows the user to create several notes and navigate between them by using the various tabs on the left.

Now I want these notes to save in the local storage so I added the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).unload(saveSettings);
        loadSettings();
    });

    function saveSettings() {
        localStorage.notes = $('#notes').html();
    }

    function loadSettings() {
        $('#notes').html(localStorage.notes);
    }
}
```

It works in a certain degree. Meaning the whole div is saved in the cache but for some reason when I reload the page I can see the different tabs but not the text that I wrote.
Obviously the whole point is to save the notes so it's a problem if I can't see the text that I wrote.

I am unfortunately not so knowledgeable on javascript & jquery, so I have no idea what to do.

I believe it would be smarter to save each tabs and textarea individually in the cache instead of the whole Div but I also don't know how to do that.

If anyone can help me or at least guide me, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest you store the notes in an array (and use JSON.stringify to store it in the local storage) rather than the raw HTML.   I can't tell (yet) why the contents of your `<textarea>` nodes aren't getting saved.

Comment: @Alnitak: _“I can't tell (yet) why the contents of your <textarea> nodes aren't getting saved”_ – because what the user inputs into form fields can not be “read” using .html() - difference between DOM attributes and properties comes into play here again.

Comment: @CBroe yes, that's what I've determined (and had already put in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

The "value" of a `<textarea>` field apparently does not become part of the `innerHTML` of that element, it's accessible instead via the `.val()` jQuery method or the `.value` DOM property.

It would be better to abstract the content of the tabs into e.g. an array, and recreate the DOM elements around those when you load the page.

This would ensure that if you redesign your content that old notes don't appear with the wrong rendering.

For example (untested):

```
function saveSettings() {
    var notes = $('#notes textarea').map(function(ix, el) {
        return el.value;
    });
    localStorage.notes = JSON.stringify(notes);
}

function loadSettings() {
    var notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.notes);

    // rebuilding divs left as exercise
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your approach seems to be the best but as you can see the tabs have different IDs, so how would I use .val() for each tabs that have a different ID? Would it be too much to ask you to modify my jsfiddle with your approach?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you that you can use cookies to make notes 
In this is way you can store users notes for longer time

for more information about cookies you can check here :

http://www.ms2fun.com/2015/01/javascript-cookies-getcookie-setcookie.html

Comment: `localStorage` is actually better than cookies for this, and the OP's problem actually has nothing to do with storage, but relates to how the user supplied content is stored in the DOM.